# logging exceptions in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I have the following :

```
### running with Python 3 
import logging 
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)                                                                                                              
logger.setLevel('DEBUG')                                                                           
logger.exception('this is an exception')
```

The output is:

```
this is an exception
NoneType: None
```

What do i need to do to get rid of that "NoneType: None" output?

Comment: `logging.exception`, per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception), *"should only be called from an exception handler."* *What* exception are you trying to log?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  Huh, the docs are actually kinda wrong here. It's supported to use `logging.exception` and `logging.error` passing in an exception instance (or a tuple), but they didn't document that.  Looks like support was added in Python 3 but the docs weren't updated from 2.7 versions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Usually, a `logger.exception` method would be called from within an `except` block. Stdlib [`logging` is trying to append the exception info](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception), but you don't have any exception info available because you're not logging from within an `except` block.

The `NoneType: None` output ultimately comes from the result of a `sys.exc_info()` call, which returns `(None, None, None)` for the type, value, and traceback. The `logging` module doesn't bother to check whether they're valid or not.

Lame workaround: suppress the exception info detail with `exc_info=False`

```
logger.exception('this is an exception', exc_info=False)
```

Slightly less lame: don't use `logger.exception` when there is no exception

```
logger.error('this is an exception...haha not really')
```

Best: use `logger.exception` from within an exception handler

```
try:
    # risky code
except Exception:
    logger.exception('this is an exception')
```

If you have an exception *instance* that was caught earlier which you want to log, and you're not within an except block, passing the exception instance explicitly will do the right thing:

```
try:
    # risky code
except Exception as err:
    myerror = err
# other code
logger.exception('this is an exception', exc_info=myerror)
```